# Why does using 'location' in payload break push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I'm struggling with trying to send a geopoint in a push payload from Parse Cloud Code. As noted in the code, if I comment out the line where I add `'latitude':location.latitude` my push notifications arrive.

With the line in, however, I get `success` called, but the push is shown as having 0 recipients in the Parse Push control panel. And of course it never arrives on the other end.

Location.latitude is not null, it's a normal long decimal. Location is a Geopoint, i.e. `"location":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":0.40281958847904,"longitude":-0.337979459707093}`

Help?

```
var pushData = {
'aps': {
    'alert':'Here lies treasure ' + placeName,
    'badge':'Increment',
    'priority':10,
    'sound':"Ting.caf",
    'content-available':1
    },
'latitude': location.latitude, // if I comment this line out everything works fine
'senderName':senderName,
'sender': senderID,
'request': request.id
};

Parse.Push.send({
    channels: [recipient],
    data: pushData
}, {
    success: function() { 
        console.log("Pushed for " + recipient);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(error) + " sending push for " + recipient);
    }
});
```

One other bit of information, setting this key removes the 'apple' from the list of channels under "target" in the Parse Push Console. Top one includes the key, bottom one doesn't:

[image: screenshot showing one success and one failure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for iOS:
Your notification payload seems nice and complex, are you sure you will fit within around 230 bytes limit (absolute limit is 256 but headers also eat some bytes) 
(if all strings in your case were around 5-10 chars you can easily hit the limit)

You could try to truncate all fields to single/double letter values ('senderName' -> 'sn')?

For other platforms you could also try to cast location.latitude to string with just 4-6 decimal digits ?